# I am executing n no. of processes where n is could be between 5 - 50. Each process is making multiple dml operations on postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

The processes would be running 24*7 and will be re-started periodically (like once in a week).

In this case which is a better option :

1. Opening a postgres connection per processes which will persist until the life of the process.
2. Opening a postgres connection pool and sharing it among the processes.

Comment: You have a third option, which is that each process opens a connection when required, does its thing, then closes it, and does that every time it needs to access pg. So I guess another thing to consider is: with what frequency will they be needing to access pg?

Comment: @404 That doesn't sounds like a good option in most cases.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe If the process only needs to query at a low frequency, then that is how I would implement it. That's how we do it at work anyway, not that I came up with the design but I agree with it. Seems wasteful to keep a connection open when it won't be used most of the time. In places which require higher frequency access, I'd keep the connection and reuse it.

Comment: my processes will be active 24*7 and in that span execute a series of tasks required several dml operations. This will be repeated throughout the day. The processes will be stopped and re-started once weekly.

Answer (score 0):

The main objective is that there are not too many PostgreSQL connections at the same time, otherwise the danger increases that toi many of them will become active at the same time, thereby overloading the database.

So as long as you have some 20 processes, you can keep things simple and have a persistent connection per process. With many processes, you need a  connection pool.

Comment: what will be the advantage of using persistent connection over connection pool for 10 - 30 processes.

Comment: As long as the connections are persistent, the only advantage of a connection pool is fewer connections.

Comment: @CodeHacker I think you are asking the wrong way around.  What is the advantage of injecting another moving part into the system when it serves no purpose?  It is just one more thing to be maintained, be (mis)configured, have bugs, and introduce latency.