# Postgres - pycopg2 - which is better - opening new connection for each process (50+ processes running 24*7) or a connection pool

Tags: python, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I'm trying to connect with my postgresql database with multiple processes.
Which of them would be the most efficient among these two?

```py
from psycopg2 import pool

pg_conn = pg.connect()
```

OR

```py
pg_conn_pool = psycopg2.pool.ThreadedConnectionPool()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am executing n no. of processes where n is could be between 5 - 50. Each process is making multiple dml operations on postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59766207/i-am-executing-n-no-of-processes-where-n-is-could-be-between-5-50-each-proce)

Comment: A connection pool - it is designed for this exact purpose